# Order of boolean operations in Spring Data generated queries

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, boolean-logic

Would this Spring Data JPA method:

`List<Foo> findAllByXOrYAndZ();`

represent which logical case of the two:

- `(X || Y) && Z`
- `X || (Y && Z)`

And how can I represent the other one with Spring Data generated queries?

Answer (score 0):

It represents: **`X || (Y && Z)`.**

The Query that Hibernate will execute, in the case of `List<Foo> findAllByXOrYAndZ();`,  would be:

```
select
   *columns*
from
   *table*
where
   x = ?
   or y = ?
   and z = ?
```

Pay attention to the WHERE clause of the query. Knowing that **AND has higher precedence over OR operation**, the equivalent WHERE clause would be:

```
where
   x = ? or ( y = ? and z = ? )
```

Hibernate automatically removes the parentheses because they are not needed.

I generally would **avoid** using such methods, because they are not very readable. You should use a Custom Query with @Query instead.